# Decrement Value in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, barcode

I've made this little code for the barcode generator and I want to add a button to decrement one lable if the user fails and added more than he wants how can I do it?

code is :

```
namespace BarcodeGeneratorC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt;
        ReportDocument cry = new ReportDocument();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.TableName = "DataTable1";
            dt.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Company Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Barcode", typeof(string));

        }

        private void btn_barcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                int Endcount = Convert.ToInt32(tb_loop.Text);
                for (int i = 1; i <= Endcount; i++)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(cb_product.Text, tb_price.Text + " IQD", tb_cname.Text, tb_enterbarcode.Text);
                    cry.Load("CrystalReport1.rpt");
                    cry.SetDataSource(dt);
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cry;
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the row from the DataTable and refresh/reload the report.